# FB.setSize or FB.setAutoGrow not working for height of pagetab app

Tags: facebook, iframe, tabs, height, facebook-page

This problem has occurred recently and I don't know why. I haven't changed my code anything so I'm assuming Facebook has something to do with it.

I make apps to fit in pagetabs on Facebook and to resize the height of the iframe I have always used the following method:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Lots of code -->
</head>
<body>
<!-- Lots of code -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">  
   window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
     appId: '00000000000000' // A real ID of course
    });
    FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();

   };
     (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/sv_SE/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see I'm using the FB.Canvas.setAutoResize method to resize the iframe. Now, I know that this method is beeing removed but I have tried to use setAutoGrow() and setSize() and pass in a specific height and width but not even that will work. And all my apps I have created that used to work fine using one of these methods all look terrible now when the height of the iframe only is 800 px.

Help is very much appreciated!
Best Regards

Comment: check your application settings, there is an option to set fixed width or height of canvas, you should use fluid / auto

Comment: I have already tried that. I have tried setting it to fixed and fluid. Nothing happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TRY THIS**

```
  <div id="fb-root">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    FB.init({
        appId: 'APPID',
        status: true, // check login status
        cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml: true// parse XFBML
    });
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.Canvas.setSize();
    }

    FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow(7);
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I applied your code and it worked. Then when I changed back to my code it worked too. Guess it was some issue with the cache or something!